# Can't use Backbone.js save method returned object (except in console)?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, response

I have a backbone application on Rails, and it responds with the new model attributes.

```
  save: ->
    self = @
    attributes = {}
    @$el.children('.table').find('input, textarea').each ->
      attributes[ $(@).attr 'name' ] = $(@).val()
      self.$el.find('.text.' + $(@).attr('name') ).html $(@).val()

    response = @model.save attributes
    category = response.responseText

    window.response = response
    window.category = category

    console.log response
    console.log response.responseText
```

In the console, response returns an object, but response.responseText doesn't.  HOWEVER, if I go into console and type in "response.responseText;" (because I bound response to the window), it returns text.

Is there a reason why I would not be able to access that variable in my backbone.js function, but I can in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone makes **AJAX** request, that is, **asynchronous** request.

```
console.log response
console.log response.responseText
```

Those lines are probably executed **before** the server actually responds (you don't know for sure, but as you have very little code before, it is). Use the **callbacks** that are made to deal with that:

```
response = @model.save attributes success: =>
  console.log response.responseText
```

Or other callbacks, like `done` and such. You could also use the events like `sync`.